# Is it safe to use the "p256dh" or "endpoint" keys values of the push notification subscription object as an identifier within the back-end?

Tags: javascript, flask, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

When a user create a subscription through the [PushManager.subscribe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe), given the `applicationServerKey` (VAPID public key), it creates a valid subscription the contents of which can be sent and stored in the database. The content sent to the database looks something like the following:

```
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dpH5lCsTSSM:APA91bHqjZxM0VImWWqDRN7U0a3AycjUf4O-byuxb_wJsKRaKvV_iKw56s16ekq6FUqoCF7k2nICUpd8fHPxVTgqLunFeVeB9lLCQZyohyAztTH8ZQL9WCxKpA6dvTG_TUIhQUFq_n",
"keys": {
    "p256dh":"BLQELIDm-6b9Bl07YrEuXJ4BL_YBVQ0dvt9NQGGJxIQidJWHPNa9YrouvcQ9d7_MqzvGS9Alz60SZNCG3qfpk=",
    "auth":"4vQK-SvRAN5eo-8ASlrwA=="
    }
}
```

Source: [Introduction to push notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#how_web_push_works)

This object provides the unique endpoint in which the back-end server knows where to call in order to send the push notification to and does so authenticating with the corresponding VAPID private key.

Google states that the unique identifier for this endpoint is opaque and no personal data can be determined from it.

> The identifier is opaque. As a developer, you can't determine any
> personal data from it. Also, it is not stable, so it can't be used to
> track users.

Following this tutorial from [Surya Sankar](https://medium.com/@suryasankar/how-to-setup-basic-web-push-notification-functionality-using-a-flask-backend-1251a5413bbe), the entire subscription object can be sent to the server and stored within the database for use later when sending push notifications to the associated browser/device. However, before recording the entry into the database, it compares to see if an entry with the same contents have already been recorded as to not create duplicates.

```
@app.route("/api/push-subscriptions", methods=["POST"])
def create_push_subscription():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    subscription = PushSubscription.query.filter_by(
        subscription_json=json_data['subscription_json']
    ).first()
    if subscription is None:
        subscription = PushSubscription(
            subscription_json=json_data['subscription_json']
        )
        db.session.add(subscription)
        db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({
        "status": "success"
    })
```

Source: [push_subscriptions_api.py](https://gist.github.com/SuryaSankar/8c8ea67978f91953673b0d19be24e073#file-push_subscriptions_api-py)

Since the entire subscription object is utilized with `webpush` to trigger a push notification, I understand that the entire subscription object will need to be sent to the server.

```
from pywebpush import webpush, WebPushException
import json
from flask import current_app


def trigger_push_notification(push_subscription, title, body):
    try:
        response = webpush(
            # Uses entire subscription object stored in database as parameter
            subscription_info=json.loads(push_subscription.subscription_json),
            data=json.dumps({"title": title, "body": body}),
            vapid_private_key=current_app.config["VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY"],
            vapid_claims={
                "sub": "mailto:{}".format(
                    current_app.config["VAPID_CLAIM_EMAIL"])
            }
        )
        return response.ok
    except WebPushException as ex:
        if ex.response and ex.response.json():
            extra = ex.response.json()
            print("Remote service replied with a {}:{}, {}",
                  extra.code,
                  extra.errno,
                  extra.message
                  )
        return False


def trigger_push_notifications_for_subscriptions(subscriptions, title, body):
    return [trigger_push_notification(subscription, title, body)
            for subscription in subscriptions]
```

Source: [webpush_handler.py](https://gist.github.com/SuryaSankar/5a75506e924bbc052cd15a3022167f7b#file-webpush_handler-py)

This follows the guidelines under the documentation for this library ([pywebpush](https://pypi.org/project/pywebpush/)) which states to do the following under their [Usage](https://github.com/web-push-libs/pywebpush#usage) section in their README.md file.

With that, I am curious about **what parts of the subscription object contain sensitive information (i.e. `"auth"`)?** The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/getKey) for `PushSubscription.getKey()` states that `"auth"` is an authentication secret and `"p256dh"` is a public key. Given that push [notifications can only be used over HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#how_web_push_works), the communication between the client and server would be secure.

**When trying to reference this subscription from the front-end, what part of this subscription object can I use as an identifier to reference this entry within the database?**

(i.e. A `GET` request to this endpoint would look like the following `https:/example.com/client/push-subscription/<subscription-object-identifier>`)

I do not think I can use the entire subscription object as an identifier for this endpoint as it would expose the content under `"auth"`. **Could I use the content under `"endpoint"` or `"p256dh"` as the identifier as they would be unique and would not expose any sensitive data?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can safely use the `endpoint` as a unique identifier in your database and in the frontend calls to the backend.

We have been using it in the Pushpad Javascript SDK since 2015 without any problem.

For example, you can use the endpoint as an identifier when you make a call from Javascript to the backend in order to store data for that specific subscription.

An endpoint can be considered unique and secret (since it contains a long random token).

This is true now and it was also true at the beginning of the standard... in the past the `keys` and payload were not even present and the `endpoint` alone was used for everything, including fetching the new notifications from the application server.

For the `keys` I would simply keep them secret in the database and not use them as identifiers.